# How to remove extra spaces between words in excel or google sheet?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to remove spaces from the words. e.g. **Tube and Light** should be **Tubeandlight**. Also i need it to be an arrayformula and concatenate H,E and F columns.

Using Google sheet / excel. I guess the formula should work both on google sheet and excel.

Here is the result of the formula =arrayformula(if((H4:H)="","",trim(E4:E)&"-"&trim(F4:F)&"-"&trim(H4:H))) .**Tube and light-blue and green-120 meter**. It does trim but i am not able to remove the spaces between the words

How can i remove the text between the words?
Thanks

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IF(H4:H="",,E4:E&"-"&F4:F&"-"&H4:H), " ", ))
```

Comment: awesome. so the substitute it is!